# Web API method per derived class or only one method that can serve all?

Tags: c#, api, inheritance

I have a couple of derived classes `B` and `C` inheriting from the same base class `A`:

```
public class A {}
public class B : A {}
public class C : A {}
```

I need to create an HTTP POST API method to consume each of the concrete classes. Is it better to have one method that accepts the base class or create separate methods for each derived class?

```
[Route("send/Base")]
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult SendPricingLetter(A model)
{
    // do some type checking and perform logic    
}
```

I am using a factory to do type checking and set appropriate fields for each class and looks like it can get unmanageable pretty quickly.

Or

```
[Route("send/ConcreteB")]
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult SendSomeOther(B model)
{
    // No type checking required and perform logic     
}

[Route("send/ConcreteC")]
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult SendStuff(C model)
{
    // No type checking required and perform logic    
}
```

Comment: I wonder whether your sample code is too abstract. The method `SendPricingLetter` will always get you an `A` object, never a `B` or `C`. What kind of "some type checking" would you do?

Comment: I can post any object that inherits from A. Like in any method that expects a base class as parameters. Then I have to some kind of check to find out the derived class.

Comment: Would you please update your question and explain how this test is supposed to work? You get an object of type `A` with no indication whatsoever whether the originally posted object was a `B` or a `C`. This is a Web call. You lose inheritance information due to the serialization. What you receive is a serialized `B` or `C`; however, what you get in as a parameter is a plain `A` thanks to the de-serialization.

Comment: Haven't tried that in a web call yet. But for methods it does work.

Comment: Well, then try for Web methods and you'll be surprised. I'll post an answer :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method `SendPricingLetter` will always receive an instance of `A` even though you may post a `B` or `C`. This is related to the way how de-serialization works. Your approach to "do some type checking" will not work as you will always have to deal with objects of type `A`. There will be no indication whether they origin from `A`, `B` or `C`.

I am uncertain what your requirements are; however, in a Web API method you think about data models, not object-oriented inheritance principles. I am personally a fan of following REST principles which make you think more in a domain-oriented way.

Check whether you class modelling is correct. If so and if you really require to transport these different objects to your API then you are either offering three separate methods, one for `A`, one for `B` and one for `C`, - OR - you have a single call and deal with `A`, `B`, and `C` accordingly such as like this:

```
public class MyRequestModel
{
    public DomainModelType Type { get; set; }
    public A ToDomainObject()
    {
        switch (Type)
        {
            case DomainModelType.A:
                return new A();
            case DomainModelType.B:
                return new B();
            case DomainModelType.C:
                return new C();
            default:
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }
    }
}

[Route("Stuff")]
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Stuff(MyRequestModel requestModel)
{
    var myOriginalObject = requestModel.ToDomainObject();
    // do some type checking and perform logic
}
```

I personally would always go with explicit API calls (three in your case) unless I have a valid requirement to keep them together.

Comment: I was using explicit API calls. Just realized that Serialization phenomenon :( .However if i expect an object and cast as JObject then it will still contain all information and can cast to concrete classes. It just increase the complexity. your way is clever but i thing i will stick with the explicit endpoints.